# Automatically Install Third Party NuGet Package On Installation of Own Package

Tags: c#, nuget, sqlite-net

I've just started working with NuGet packages and can't find a solution to the following question:

I'm using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) in my NuGet package and and now users who want to use it needs to install the sqlite-net NuGet package too, as it is state on the the sqlite-net page:

"*Important: You will need to add the NuGet package to both your .NET Standard library project and your platform-dependent app project.*"

Is there a way to install the sqlite-net package automatically when my NuGet package is installed?